# Python json API format to dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, python-requests

I have a question that for which I'd really appreciate some input.

What I need is working using one library however for my curosity I'd like solve this using another library.

I'm extracting data from the world bank API and graphing a population over time. This is working using Method 1 but I would curious to have it working in the second method.

Hope this is proof that I don't need something done for homework :) I have difficulty parsing through list, dictonaries etc.

List 1 (working) = Lists containing containing multiple dictionaries (only dictionaries) which contain what I need = I can loop through and extract what I need

```
dIRL_POP = dict([(int(d['date']), float(d['value'])) for d in data if d['value'] is not None])
```

dIRL_POP is the new dictionary where i loop through the list data d times and extact the date and the value from the dictionary

## Code

```
import wbdata

data = wbdata.get_data("SP.POP.TOTL", country="IRL") #list

dIRL_POP = dict([(int(d['date']), float(d['value']))

for d in data if d['value'] is not None])
```

Comment : dIRL_POP is the new dictionary where i loop through the list data d times and extract the date and the value from the dictionary

List 2 (not solved) = List contains multiple lists of dictionaries and multiple dictionaries. As for point one only the list of dictionaries is of interest. How can I ignore the dictionaries and only look at the lists?

## Code

```
uri = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/irl/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?format=json'

connIRL= requests.get(uri)

connIRL_response = connIRL.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **isinstance** to check the type of an element.

```
mylist = [[{1: 2, 3:3}], {1: 2, 3:3}, [{2: 3, 4:5}], {2: 3, 4:5}]
list_of_lists = [elem for elem in mylist if isinstance(elem, list)]
print(list_of_lists)
```

> [[{1: 2, 3: 3}], [{2: 3, 4: 5}]]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed :)